# Matching multiple keywords from a line in java

Tags: java, regex

I have a line from which multiple keywords are to be matched.  The whole keywords should be matched.

Example,

```
 String str = "This is an example text for matching countries like Australia India England";

 if(str.contains("Australia") ||
    str.contains("India") ||
    str.contains("England")){
    System.out.println("Matches");
 }else{
    System.out.println("Does not match");
 }
```

This code works fine.  But if there are too many keywords to be matched, the line grows.  **Is there any elegant way of writing the same code?**
Thanks

Comment: Put line break after every `||` and use nice indentation

Comment: The first line should read: `String str = "This is an example text for matching countries like Australia India England"`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Your can write a regular expression like this:

```
Country0|Country1|Country2
```

Use it like this:

```
String str = "This is an example text like Australia India England";

if (Pattern.compile("Australia|India|England").matcher(str).find())     
    System.out.println("Matches");
```

If you would like to know which countries has matched:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

    String str = "This is an example text like Australia India England";

    Matcher m = Pattern.compile("Australia|India|England").matcher(str);
    while (m.find())        
        System.out.println("Matches: " + m.group());
}
```

Outputs:

```
Matches: Australia
Matches: India
Matches: England
```

Answer (score 4):

Put countries to array and use small helper method. Using Set makes it even nicer, but building set of countries is bit more tedious. Something like following, but with better naming and null handling if wished:

```
String[] countries = {"Australia", "India", "England"};
String str = "NAustraliaA";
if (containsAny(str, countries)) {
    System.out.println("Matches");
}
else {
    System.out.println("Does not match");
}

public static boolean containsAny(String toCheck, String[] values) {
    for (String s: values) {
        if (toCheck.contains(s)) {
            return true;
        }
     }
    return false;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

From readability point of view, an ArrayList of strings to be matched will be elegant. A loop can be formed to check if the word is available else it will set a flag to indicate that a keyword was missing

Something like, in case all are to be matched

```
for (String checkStr : myList) {
 if(!str.contains(checkStr)) {
 flag=false;
 break;
}
}
```

in case any should match

```
for (String checkStr : myList) {
 if(str.contains(checkStr)) {
 flag=true;
 break;
}
}
```

Answer (score 2):

```
package com.test;
```

public class Program {

```
private String str;

public Program() {
    str = "This is an example text for matching countries like Australia India England";
    // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    Program program = new Program();
    program.doWork();
}

private void doWork() {

    String[] tomatch = { "Australia", "India" ,"UK"};


    for(int i=0;i<tomatch.length;i++){
    if (match(tomatch[i])) {
        System.out.println(tomatch[i]+" Matches");
    } else {
        System.out.println(tomatch[i]+" Does not match");
    }
    }
}

private boolean match(String string) {

    if (str.contains(string)) {
        return true;
    }

    return false;
}
```

}

//-----------------
output
Australia Matches
India Matches
UK Does not match